# Change Line Colour with Plotly Express

Tags: python, plotly-dash, linegraph, plotly-express

I have a plotly express figure:

`fig = px.line(data, x="DateTime", y="Gold", title="Gold Prices")`

I want to change some details, like so

```
fig.update_layout(
    line_color="#0000ff",  # ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Layout: 'line'
    line=dict(
        color='rgb(204, 204, 204)',
        width=5
    ),  # Bad property path: line
)
```

But both attempts (trying solutions I researched on here) failed, with the errors given in the comments.

I have also tried `fig = px.line(data, x="DateTime", y="Gold", title="Gold Prices", template="ggplot2", color_discrete_map={"Gold": "green"})` to no avail.

How do I make this work please?

Answer (score 20):

Try to use `.update_traces()` with `plotly.express` instead of `.update_layout()`:

```
fig.update_traces(line_color='#0000ff', line_width=5)
```

Comment: Does this work when there are multiple lines please? If so, how to set them?

Comment: Works for multiple lines but than all lines seem to have the same color, wouldn't take a color list as an input (I had just one line, but a row split). Used the indexing system from r-beginners below.

Answer (score 10):

**plotly.express**

If you want to use plotly.express, add the following settings.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y="GOOG", title='Ticker:GOOG')

fig['data'][0]['line']['color']='rgb(204, 204, 204)'
fig['data'][0]['line']['width']=5

fig.show()
```

**plotly.graph_objects**

If you are using plotly.graph_objects, you can set it in go.Scatter().

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=df['date'], y=df['GOOG'], mode='lines', line_color='rgb(204, 204, 204)', line_width=5))
fig.update_layout(title='Ticker:GOOG')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The output of each is the same, so they are one and the same.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried simply.

```
fig.add_scattergl(x=xs, y=df.y, line={'color': 'black'})
```

[Source](https://community.plotly.com/t/color-change-by-range-in-line-chart/17829/3)

Answer (score 3):

```
fig = px.line(data, x="DateTime", y="Gold", title="Gold Prices", color_discrete_map={"DateTime": "blue", "Gold": "green"})
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the "set_color" function like so:

```
fig.set_color('b')
```

or

```
fig.set_color('g')
```

where g and b can also be r for the RGB color scheme.
then
`fig.show()`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_color'`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me quite well:

```
fig = px.line(
    data, 
    x="DateTime", 
    y="Gold", 
    title="Gold Prices",
    color_discrete_sequence=["rgb(204, 204, 204)"] # This parameter do the trick.
)
```

It also works in using something like: `color_discrete_sequence=["black"]`